# PyWinAuto: How to interact with a dynamically found an application (Window Form) as another Window applicaton?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am facing that connecting to already running  window application. I was opening notepad application and then I also open another application like "SystemSettings.exe" from notepad application as "Format -> Font and click 'Show more fonts' link". Then Setting window form was opening successfully. Then I tried to connect the Setting application as below:

```
win_app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path=r"C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe")
dialogs=win_app(title='Settings')
```

**It is showing like issue**
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\*******\ dialogs=win_app(title='Settings') ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: 'Application' object is not callable`

My code sample to...

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time
from pywinauto import application
import pywinauto


ExeName="SystemSettings.exe"
Exeparth="C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel

# open notepad application 
app = Application().start("notepad",timeout=15)

main_dlg.Edit.type_keys("This is pywinauto!\n\t It's a sample text^A", 
                       with_spaces=True, 
                       with_newlines=True,
                       pause=0.2,
                       with_tabs=True)
#Opening the Font Setting subtab
app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("Format -> Font")

#Change Font
app.Font.FontComboBox.edit.type_keys("Arial")

#Open SystemSettings.exe via soft-link(Show more fonts)
app.Font.SysLink.click()

#Connet to Setting applicatin
win_app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path=r"C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe")
dialogs=win_app(title='Settings')
```

`Issue throw out : dialogs=win_app(title='Settings') ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: 'Application' object is not callabl`

**

> My Working Code

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time
from pywinauto import application
import pywinauto

ExeName="SystemSettings.exe"
Exeparth="C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel"

# open notepad application 
app = Application().start("notepad",timeout=15)


# Define main window specification

main_dlg = app.UntitledNotepad
main_dlg.wait('visible')

dlg_space=app.window(title='Untitled - Notepad')
dlg_space.wrapper_object().maximize()

print("minimize OK")
'''
Another way to define main window specification
main_dlg = app.window(title='Untitled - Notepad')
'''

#print all controls on the dialog
'''main_dlg.print_control_identifiers()'''

main_dlg.Edit.type_keys("This is pywinauto!\n\t It's a sample text^A", 
                   with_spaces=True, 
                   with_newlines=True,
                   pause=0.2,
                   with_tabs=True)
                   
time.sleep(2)

app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("Help -> About Notepad")

app.aboutNotepad.OK.click()

app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("Format -> Font")

#Change Frount style
app.Font.FontComboBox.edit.type_keys("Calibri")

time.sleep(1)

app.Font.FontStyleComboBox.edit.type_keys("Bold")

time.sleep(1)

app.Font.SizeComboBox.edit.type_keys("28")

time.sleep(1)

app.Font.SysLink.click()

time.sleep(5)


win_app =  Application().connect(title=u'Settings',class_name='ApplicationFrameWindow', timeout=10)


dialogs = win_app.Settings

print(dialogs)
print("It is OK here***")

dialogs.ApplicationFrameTitleBarWindow.type_keys("%{F4}")

time.sleep(1)

app.Font.OK.click()

print("OK button from Font dialog")

app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("File -> Exit")


print("File -> Exit click")

time.sleep(1)

app.Notepad.dontsave.click()

print("Don't Save button from confirmaiton box")
```

**

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Also note that, as the code markdown now shows, you forgot to close the string of `Exeparth`, which will cause errors.

Answer (score 2):

`win_app(title='Settings')` should be `win_app.window(title='Settings')`

Also `Exeparth="C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel` has no closing quote in your code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Now I am OK with below code:

win_app = Application().connect(title=u'Settings',class_name='ApplicationFrameWindow', timeout=10)
dialogs = win_app.Settings
dialogs.ApplicationFrameTitleBarWindow.print_control_identifiers()

Comment: Great. Please post your working code as an answer and mark this answer as accepted (check box at left side of answer). It is OK to accept your own answer. It just shows others the problem is already solved.